# jquery validation of text field not firing ajax request for valid entry

Tags: jquery-validate

I have a text field(email) in my form which checks whether the entered value is valid, if so then it will have to validate the same again my DB.

The problem is that when I type wrong its not displaying the error message that I have configured under message, instead it chooses over the default msg.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        email:{
            required: true,
            email: true,
             type: "post",
            remote:{
                url:"myservlet?verifyEmail=checkEmail",
                /* data: "verifyEmail=checkEmail", */
                type: "post",
            }  
        },
     messages:{
         email:{
             required: "Enter a valid email",
             remote: "This user is already taken"
         }
     }
    },
    highlight: function(element){
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element){
        element
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error')/* .addclass('error') */;        
        }
});

   if(('#myform').validated())
       ('#myform').submit();
```

I tried to check the network traffic i dnt see any traffic due to this request.  The bootstrap class configured under highlight and success is working fine.  This is my first time using this plugin.

Update 1: **Input controls**

```
                 <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email"> email:</label>
           <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="input-xlarge span2" name="email"/>
            </div>
         </div>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" Value="Refresh" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Update 2:

I have modified my code. Now validation rules is working, but I am still facing issues with ajax request not being fired. Any heads up on that?

Comment: Can you include the code for the actual input control(s)?

Comment: Shouldn't `if(('#myform').validated())` be `if(('#myform').validate())`

Comment: This question is tagged wrong. This is NOT for the jQuery Validation-Engine plugin. It is for jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I've update the object structure slightly, `messages` is a sibling of `rules`, not a child:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            type: "post",
            remote: {
                url: "myservlet?verifyEmail=checkEmail",
                /* data: "verifyEmail=checkEmail", */
                type: "post",
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Enter a valid email",
            remote: "This user is already taken"
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JAfKf/)

Comment: thanks for pointing out, that was a typo. Still it doesn't fire the request.

Comment: @Mark Erasmus, Tried that one too. No luck!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Also, wonder why ajax request is not being fired once I enter correct email, any idea why?. I dnt want to submit my form. Just validate my email with the entry in my DB